# Handsontable data not correctly updating after moving columns

Tags: angular, handsontable

I was trying to add a rename header functionality using Angular wrapper of handsontable.

When i tried to rename a header, it got renamed. However it got appended as a last column in the table and not on the previous headers' position.
Then i used trackby in ngfor which retained the correct position of column but now the columns are not being correctly moved.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a starting point in your code to dive into your problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: beforeColumnMove: (event, target, new_position) =>{
        if (new_position-1<=this.spData.getHeaderLength()){
          var NewHeaders=this.moveHeaders(target, new_position);
          delete(this.spData.Headers);
          this.spData.Headers=NewHeaders;
        }
      }